# Call a Class object in a Class rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a code for my project

```
Class Task < ActiveModel::Base
  belongs_to :project, inverse_of: :tasks
  attr_accessible :name
end

Class Project < ActiveModel::Base
  has_many :tasks, inverse_of: :project

  def method1
    tasks.each do |v|
      puts v.name
    end
  end
end
```

but it always complains undefined local variable or method "tasks";
I'm pretty new to ruby on rails, so I'm so confused about it because i see others's code which uses the similary way to call tasks. Can someone explain? Thank you so much!

Comment: There is no `ActiveModel::Base` constant in Rails. Also `Class` should be lowercase. If these are typos, please correct them before checking real issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Task < ActiveModel::Base

  belongs_to :project, inverse_of: :tasks

  attr_accessible :name

end

Class Project < ActiveModel::Base

  has_many :tasks, inverse_of: :project

  def method1
    tasks.each do |v|
puts v.name
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but actually it was typo about :project. sorry about it. but it still does not work. is it supposed to work?

Comment: ok. it actually complains undefined local variable or method method1.

Comment: how do you actually call this method?

Comment: basically i want to use "tasks" in project model. the association is project has many tasks. inside method1, i'm not sure if i can use "tasks" to do loop. i see others use the similar way though.

Answer (score 0):

Is it work if you change

```
def method1
  tasks.each do |v|
  puts v.name
end
```

to

```
def method1
  self.tasks.each do |v|
  puts v.name
end
```

Comment: yea it worked! but weirdly, afterwards i deleted "self." and ran the page on local machine again, it still worked...and now nothing is wrong. i have no idea what I did wrong. but anyway thank you so much!

Comment: If it worked , just accept it as answer. By the way, in method definition. ruby will try to find local variable. I dont know why  it work on you without self. but to be safe, use self to reference to current object not local variable.

Comment: I can't see any reason you need to add `self` here. Do you mind to elaborate more?

Comment: @BillyChan , to be honest, i dont know. user2775888 is also said that after implenting changes, and change back without self, it still work. You could be right, self is not necesary. But i recommend him it should. To me, it makes code more readable and to avoid calling local variable if the same name has been defined.

Comment: @bekicot, thanks for the reply. I think that's kind of taste. I myself like the concise one without self. Also in lots of reputable libs such pattern is rarely used.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the `inverse_of` option in this case. Also in methods that aceesses attributes of an object you should call this using `self.attribute`. So your code should look like this. Also to work your Tasks model should have the column `project_id` where the id of the associated Project can be stored. If these conditions are complied it should work.

task.rb

```
  belongs_to :project
```

project.rb

```
  has_many :tasks
```